# change http ref using cURL and PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am using cURL to change the HTTP ref for a site that only allow you to see their content if it's coming from search engins:

I was able to do that!

But the problem is: the IP address of the visitor the site get is not mine! it's the IP address of the site I'm using to change the ref !, here is the code:

```
echo geturl('http://example.com', 'http://referring-site.com');

function geturl($url, $referer) { 

    $headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg,text/html,application/xhtml+xml'; 
    $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive'; 
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'; 
    $useragent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)'; 

    $process = curl_init($url); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 

    $return = curl_exec($process); 
    curl_close($process); 
  return $return;
}
```

Let say I use that code on

> mysite.com

So example.com will si referring-site.com as an HTTP ref, but it thinks that the visitors IP is the same as mysite.com !!!

Ho can I get it to get the real IP address of the visitor in stead of the site's IP I use the code on?

I tried to replace

```
      return $return;
```

with

```
return "<?php 
header( 'Location: http://example.com' ) ;
?>";
```

or

```
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' Content='0; URL=http://example.com'>';
```

But it doesn't work!

Comment: Although you cant fake the IP, you an use a proxy as @Quentin suggests with curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy); and curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, '['.$username.']:['.$password.']'); if login is required. You may also want to set the user-agent to that of the visitor so their page is valid for them.

Comment: Do you mean "How do I change the returned html to point links to example.com instead of your own server??" so <a href="index.php">home</a> would be <a href="http:// example.com/index.php">home</a>

Comment: no, I need to redirect to example.com and make it think I am coming from referring-site.com with my real IP , not with my server's IP !!

Comment: curl (server-side) will get the page as if its come from referring-site.com. You can then play with the contents of that page and even display it on your domain. BUT it will not set your browsers referrer (client-side). Curl wasn't designed for that.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is proxying the request and lying about the referer. Since the request is coming from your server, it is under your control so that sort of underhand deception is possible.

There is no way for a website to induce a browser into making that sort of lie.